# Can't watch youtube videos with chromium on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Tags: flash, chromium, youtube

I've digged all over google but I can't find any solution to my problem.

Firefox works pretty well. I have this issue only with chromium and only with youtube. I have no problem watching videos at any other site with chromium.

When I try to watch a video a black screen occurs and after a while it gives me the warning "an error occurred". Weirdly, sometimes when I try a couple of refreshing it starts to play but then the issue occurs again.

I tried removing-reinstalling chromium or the flash plugin but it did not do any good.

Comment: I'm on 13.04 64 bit and it is working fine for me.  What version of Flash you using?  I'm using 11.2.202.285 successfully.  You can check here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html

Answer (score 19):

The correct answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/316722/93826

To solve the issue you have to update the chromium ffmpeg codec to the `extra` version:

`sudo apt-get remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg`

`sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. In my case, the first command removed `chromium-browser` and the second command reinstalled it. Youtube videos are now working correctly in Chromium.

Comment: You can use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`. When you run `sudo aptitude remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg` and it will inform you that `chromium-browser` depends on it, and first its proposition will be to remove `chromium-browser`. Don't agree as the second option will be to replace `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg` with `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`. And that is what we need.

Comment: Don't `remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg` (will uninstall chromium as well). You may just `install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` and it will simply replace the 1st one. You can EVEN do this WHILE HAVING CHROMIUM OPENED (how cool is that?)

Comment: this didn't work for me, I had to restart chromium first...

Answer (score 5):

I get the same error message occassionaly, but with HTML5 (at least according to right click). I am *not* in the HTML5 beta, but was years ago. Both flash en HTML5 work good on other sites.

The solution is to [re-enter the youtube HTML5 beta](https://www.youtube.com/html5), and immediately leave it again.

Comment: nope. that did not work for me. it's bit of an odd situation but it seems it's a cookie issue. when i block all youtube cookies everthings fine but can't login. i still can't find a solution.

Comment: That worked for me, I entered HTML 5 Beta, tried to watch a video, restarted the PC, tried to watch a video one more time and leaved HTML 5 Beta, gone to a random video and it is now working.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The video is still played in the html5 player no matter how what state that toggle is in. The only temporary work around I have at the moment is to switch to the embed link youtube.com/v/videoidgoeshere

Comment: @Gerry The above did not work for me either. But the [answer by voiger](http://askubuntu.com/a/379909/136120) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Youtube's HTML5 Player

   An option would be viewing your YouTube videos using HTML5 instead of flash.

   You just have to enter the [Youtube HTML5 trial](http://youtube.com/html5) and enable HTML5 viewing, since Chromium offers almost full support of HTML5.
2. Fixing Adobe Flash

   [How do I fix flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)
3. 'Aid' Flash at Chromium

   Type `chrome://plugins/` in the address bar you can disable/enable e.g. PPAPI or NPAPI Flash Players.

Answer (score 1):

Add `&nohtml5=1` to the end of the url to force the page to using flash instead.

As a webdev who loves html5 and really dislikes flash I find it ironic that I'm suggesting this, but until Google fixes whatever is wrong with it's player, this is the only solution I could get to work.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to some people, me too (albeit on 12.04). I went to firefox and the same video plays. It seems that if you disable HTML5 on youtube then the video plays also in chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with Chromium on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. Even changing to HTML5 didn't change anything, therefore I don't think it could be a flash issue.

After playing with the settings I discovered, that changing the User Agent to "Google Chrome on Windows" solves the problem. All videos are loading again, maybe Google blocks some old Chrome/Chromium versions, as I haven't installed the latest version for sure.

Anyhow, using the extension "User Agent Switcher" offers a simple solution here.