# Can not watch any videos on Youtube using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, flash, adobe

I have been trying to solve this issue but no luck so far. I tried two of these [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300104/cant-watch-youtube-videos-with-chromium-on-ubuntu-13-04-64-bit) and [link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576562/apt-way-to-get-adobe-flash-player-latest-version-for-linux-not-working/576569#576569)links out of many. I also manually installed the flash from [Adobe](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect) here but no luck.
I can hear only the audio but not the video but in Firefox videos just works fine.

Could someone help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second link is dead. Do you have the extras package? Run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: I have that too but no luck. I will update the link now .

Comment: Not actually. I just did it right now but the same issue

Comment: Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M

Comment: I am using the alternative one x.org x server once I use the 352.63 or latest it did not work lets say 2 months before when I tried.

Comment: yeah you are right.It was the GPU. I did not realise since I tried to install 2 months before with kernel 4.4 but driver did not work so I had to choose the alternative one. now with version 322.63 it just started working.

Comment: If you write an answer I will upvote it.thanks

Comment: I am glad this was fixed so quickly, the next suggestion was going to be complex :)

Comment: After restarting the computer same problem, I am still confused why it is happening

Comment: OK I do have another suggestion for you. Open Chrome and in the address bar put `chrome://plugins` now open the little `[+] Details`. in the flash plugins section, you should see at lest two options, disable all options accept the top one (pepper flash) and restart chrome. Be careful to only disable the flash ones.

Comment: Tried it but no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try to disable pepper flash and enable the other one, don't forget to restart chrome after. Also if my answer does not work, please remove the accept, so others know this is open again.

Comment: Actually, I did try them but no luck and also tried different versions of NVIDIA drivers for that GPU.

Comment: One more thing, to try is remove the flash you got from the adobe site, if you go to the web site you linked and click the apt link again, it should open software center and you can click remove, then do a reboot.

Comment: I did it before I posted that question But forgot to mention it in the question  before.Sorry for that.It did not work out . Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by a lack of Nvidia drivers.

Simply running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

will fix the issue.