# Can't watch video in any website Ubuntu 14.04 Chromium

Tags: 14.04, radeon, chromium, amd-graphics

I saw this post from yesterday on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780556/can-not-watch-any-videos-on-youtube-using-ubuntu-14-04/781049#781049)
and my problem is very similiar, except the pc has a AMD Radeon HD 8400 instead and I really don't know how to handle with this bug.

It's recent (one week), probably some feature missing in chromium, because I can listen the sound, but no picture, and everything works fine in firefox.

I got all the updates, except the last kernel (rollback the dist-upgrade because triggered another issue with the virtualbox).
But now I have no idea how far I need go to put everything back working as before, and I'm seeking here for your guidance.

Thank you for your time and support ;)

**Hi again.
I have tested all the options suggested in the reply's, but none resolve the issue, and it's not duplicate with the suggested one.
I haven't the flash installed, always watched in html5 (I think) with 0 problems, but now i installed that too, noting changed.
It seems to me, that now chromium can't decode the video or it's too heavy to handle with it, but shows all the ads, and notes.
I don't know where to got the AMD Radeon HD 8400 drivers (none appears suggested in additional drivers)
Thanks again!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't watch youtube videos with chromium on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300104/cant-watch-youtube-videos-with-chromium-on-ubuntu-13-04-64-bit)

Comment: If the duplicate is not working for you, first update chromium and the flash plugin `sudo apt-get upgrade chromium flashplugin-installer` and try again, as you say you rolled back an update, this may be your issue.

Comment: Also, as you have 14.04, do you have the drivers for that chip? Look in the app `additional drivers`

Answer (score 0):

First Step:

You are probably missing a plug-in on Chrome. Try looking online for any available plugins for Ubuntu, or check the file repositories.

Last resort:

Either that, or your Radeon graphics isn't liking that specific browser. Canonical has dropped a lot of support on AMD Radeon drivers, and AMD Radeon has a horrendous reputation on Ubuntu, when it comes to stability and support. From my experience.....Let's just say that AMD Radeon ended my Ubuntu installs on a few of my PCs.

Nvidia has a way better reputation in Ubuntu. I recommend switching to Nvidia. Nvidia isn't perfect, and you can and will run into some problem sometimes, but at least you won't have a bad graphics experience like AMD Radeon.

But then again, it's probably Chrome. The best advice I could give you if that's the case, is that you need to switch to Firefox. I find Firefox more stable than Chrome.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Switching GPU or browser does not really off a solution to the issue, it would be better to fix the troubleshoot the problem first and switch as a last resort.

Comment: Just edited my post, ty for the suggestion.