# how to fix "could not load shockwave flash"

Tags: flash, youtube

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 32bit. I can't watch youtube videos in firefox or chromium. i installed chrome, but it will not run. here are some details and the things i have tried:

flash is installed in the software center. i tried uninstalling it, and reinstalling it.
tried uninstalling flash, and installing flash player 11 from the canonical partners section of the software center.
installed ubuntu restricted extras. tried
the process described here which attempt to use chrome's version of flash:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/how-to-make-chromium-use-flash-player.html

tried installing chrome and using that instead, but chrome will not start from dash home. when i tried to run it from terminal, i got the "system error, do you want to report it" message.

i would really like to get flash working for chromium, as firefox is pretty slow on this computer (it is old, with an amd athlon xp 2200+ processor).

i'd prefer not to have to use windows version of chrome under wine because i need to keep things simple for other people using this computer.

thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: For YouTube you can try with HTML5: http://askubuntu.com/questions/234871/youtube-says-this-video-is-currently-unavailable

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that my processor (amd athlon xp 2200+) does not support the sse2 instruction set, which is required for the latest versions of flash. I followed the instructions here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxquestions-org-member-success-stories-23/getting-flash-plug-in-to-work-with-older-cpus-4175420481/

and it works now.

Quoting from the source:

> 1. Check your CPU by entering this command in a terminal emulator:

```
    cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

> If the Flags line doesn’t contain `sse2` (`sse` won’t do), then you need to use version 10 of the plug-in.
>
> 2. Check that you do have the wrong version. In Firefox, enter the url `about:plugins`, in Opera `opera:plugins`, or in Chrome `chrome://plugins`, and see if Shockwave Flash is version 11.
>
> If (1) and (2) showed that you need to change the plug-in, there’s no need to uninstall and re-install: just changing the plug-in library file is sufficient.
>
> 3. First find where the file `libflashplayer.so` is kept. The most likely places are `/usr/lib/flash-plugin` or `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin`. If it’s not there, look for a nearby folder with the name of you browser’s provider — e.g. for Firefox, that would be `/usr/lib/mozilla` — and that will contain a symbolic link to `libflashplayer.so`.
> 4. Download the Flash package. Currently the address for the last issue of version 10 is http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get...20_archive.zip
>      If it’s not there, check at http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/...-versions.html
> 5. Open the file with your archive manager (or at the command-line if you prefer). Inside is a folder called 10.3.183.20 and inside that is another archive `flashplayer_10_3r183_20_linux.tar.gz` and inside that is `libflashplayer.so`. Extract it.
> 6. Now move it to the correct destination. The command will be
>
>    ```
>    su -c "mv -f Downloads/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flash-plugin"
>    ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>    sudo mv -f Downloads/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flash-plugin
> ```
>
> Obviously use the correct addresses if mine don’t apply.