# External links to YouTube result in "video currently unavailable" in Chromium

Tags: 12.04, chromium, youtube

BTW I don't consider this a duplicate as I am strictly speaking not troubleshooting codecs.  I have no problem playing you tube videos, if they are started from within the youtube website.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
Linux xxxx 3.8.0-35-generic #52~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:24:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Consistently, if I copy a link to a Youtube clip from any source, say Pidgin, and paste&go said link into Chromium, it results in "This video is currently unavailable". If I go to the same video after searching for it from Youtube, still in chromium, video runs just fine.

This would imply it has nothing to do with flash/html5/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg.

- Videos work fine if I start them from the Youtube site.
- Videos fail if I paste&go copied links.

In fact, if I pick a random video which is playing.  Copy the URL. Open a new tab and paste&go, it results in the "This video is currently unavailable" message.

So far, no explicit question in here, so I guess I should ask one. Where would I even begin troubleshooting this?

Asked to edit my "question" with what I've done to TS from thread [Youtube says "This video is currently unavailable"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234871/youtube-says-this-video-is-currently-unavailable)

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling chromium-codecs-ffmpeg, as well as the -extra variant. http://www.youtube.com/html5 claims I am using the default player and presents me the option to try html5.  This would imply I am not using html5.
I have cleared cookies.

Once I realized chromium has no problems with playing any video if I start it from a link within the youtube site, I really stopped troubleshooting the actual player.

I can play any video, I just have to start it from within the youtube page.
It is when I paste&go from a copied link that it always results in the error message.

I have not tried a proxy. I can do that later and update.

Proxying makes no difference.

Comment: This is an ongoing problem for me too; I've stopped using Chromium for that reason. I've also filled numerous feedback forms, but they only fix it for the video that I file the form for- eg "Little Black Submarines".