# Adobe Shockwave Flash player shows error screen on youtube player(Firefox)

Tags: firefox, flash

Adobe Shockwave Flash player 11.2.202.378 on Firefox shows an error screen on youtube player like this

[image: error screen]

And not able to play anything no matter what. Had the same problem with chromium and fixed it with the solution explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234871/youtube-says-this-video-is-currently-unavailable/316722#316722). Any help?? Thanks in advance.

Then came the update from ubuntu. Now flash works with some minor bugs

Comment: Youtube has problems right now, wait for a while and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a problem with Flash player, try to use HTML5 player instead. Turn off Flash plugin at the `about:addons` page, and try again.

Comment: i removed the flash plug-in and installed the html5 add-on, but it still asks for the adobe flash player on youtube

Comment: Go to https://www.youtube.com/html5 and if there is a button "Request the HTML5 player", click it.

Comment: still shows the error screen and asks for flash activation. And by clicking that button, the browser supports are HTMLVideoElement and WebM VP8. rest of the  Media Source Extensions, MSE & H.264, MSE & WebM VP9 are not supported